# Please raise the tag creation reputation threshold on Meta

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, meta, privileges, tag-creation

Similar to [what was done on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51949/should-the-create-new-tag-threshold-be-increased), I would like the threshold for creating new tags to be increased on Meta.

I'm proposing a new threshold of 1,000 reputation (from the current 99) -- this is negotiable with Jeff, of course.

- The proposed threshold is currently 226 users, which should be more than enough people to manage the change
- New tags on Meta should be even more rare than on SO -- chances are if a user is having a problem with a certain feature, there's already going to be a tag in the system for that; or, an experienced user will be able to create a proper tag the first time
- This effectively prevents tag pollution from off-topic posts by new/inexperienced users ([this example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/55441/revisions) and [this example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/55562/revisions) each generated 2 new tags)

Comment: I don't see why the tag reputation requirement was so low in the first place..

Comment: Nitpick: 1000 seems too high to me.  I support the concept, though, so +1.

Comment: @Earlz: I think the idea was that new users could ask about a problem that had never been discussed before. I'm not sure that worked in practice.

Comment: @Pop: What threshold would you suggest instead of 1,000? (Getting input; not being argumentative.)

Comment: @Jon, no hostility detected or offense taken.  I think 500 should do it.  I don't pretend to know every user on Meta, but looking at the Users page, I don't see any >500-ers I would actively distrust and do recognize numerous people I would trust.

Comment: If this passes I am going on a tag-creation rampage.

Comment: @Pop: Agreed, I would trust them too, but that isn't the same as being familiar with how Meta works. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/can-reputation-be-transferred-here-from-other-non-stack-overflow-websites

Comment: @The: Since when has a feature request stopped you from doing that? :D

Comment: +1.  Currently, any associated account can create a tag which seems a bit lenient. Related query: If a question was transferred here from one of the other sites, would it recreate any non-existing tags here even if the user had less than the required rep?

Comment: @Andy: Yes. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migration+tags

Comment: How about we set the new tag creation threshold to 14700? :D

Comment: @Ether: k, just give me a couple weeks. :D

Comment: @Jon, in this case, by "trust" I meant "I would trust them to understand how Meta works."  But yeah, it's clearly a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I agree -- I raised it to 500 on meta.