# How do I flag a post that is not a question?

Tags: discussion, questions, flags, meta

How do I flag a post that is not a question here on Meta Stack Exchange?

Examples:

- [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)
- [Announcing the Stacks Editor Beta release!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380295/announcing-the-stacks-editor-beta-release)
- [Please raise the tag creation reputation threshold on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55490/please-raise-the-tag-creation-reputation-threshold-on-meta)

I couldn't find the right option.

Comment: Welcome. Hey, you don't want to flag _these_ posts, do you? If you rephrased your question like "why these posts are among questions since they are not really questions?" I think it would not gather so many downvotes

Comment: I see why people downvote this question, they either think it is a silly question, or that one shouldn't downvote these examples (with which I agree). But I rather have a new user that asks a question like this instead of going on a downvoting or flagging spree. This question also serves as an excellent reference for future visitors.

Comment: @Luuklag well. 1) Currently even though the net score is -10, OP actually has positive reputation change of +12 (40-28) out of it. 2) "have a new user that asks a question like this" - true, but does it mean we should upvote based on this alone?

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard I don't care so much about the reputation. But now it could feel that OP is being penalised for asking a "basic" question. At the same time no-one has found a duplicate, so this apparently hasn't been asked before and thus it's a good thing to document, and hence a valuable question to ask. It's just sad to see that people don't see the same value in this post as I do, but there is nothing I can, or wan't, to change about that.

Comment: @Luuklag well, in this specific case the first comment is right on spot, the question has good potential, but it's wasted due to asking the wrong question. I consider editing it myself.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well - I think you mean those *questions* that are not obviously questions.

In the *context* of meta sites, especially main meta, we *sometimes* need to do things differently. Each of the posts you're asking about is an example of a kind of post that serves a purpose.

Questions are used by staff for feature announcements and tracking, with 'answers' being bugs or even questions. In the absence of a proper issue tracking system for many SE elements available to the community, and our comfort with the platform - in many cases this is the first point of contact *even* for elements that are open source and on GitHub.

We use sandboxes so users can test features. Sometimes people even have a little fun with them. On occasion, due to the age of the platform (and maybe the users), we might have to try out certain behaviours of the site to improve documentation.

We make feature requests (and this is a *core* role of meta). This lets the company know what the *users* feel they need.  If we can't do these, meta literally has no point.

Basically all the examples you gave are posts of the sort we actually welcome on meta.

In these cases you *don't* and flags will be rejected. A critical role of meta that's often forgotten is to be a way for *two way* communication between the network's staff and the community as well as between the moderators and communities. These seeming *exceptions* to a strict definition of a question enable us to use meta as it's intended.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that because Because other sites are very strict in this case. (ex: StackOverFlow)

Comment: @Minecraft On the main Stack overflow site. But on meta stack overflow these kind of questions are allowed

Comment: Journeyman Geek, what do you mean by "tracking" in "*Questions are used by staff for feature announcements and __tracking__*"?

Comment: Well - to keep track of things, in the context of being used as an improvised method of people reporting issues (whether or not its tagged as status-review or not) or getting input. Consider the way the second question OP has asked about is used -its literally using SE to introduce a feature, and get and keep track of issues and feedback for the feature.

Comment: @Journeyman so wouldn't "follow-up" be a better word to use?

Answer (score 7):

Remember that if you ever see a post that you think is not useful, then there is a way that you can notify the community of your perspective, which is by downvoting.

I do not think that any of the three posts you indicated warrant a downvote.

Think of flags as being your tool of last resort, and when you do use them that should only be for the very specific cases described in their guidance (see [Flagging a post for moderator review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24560/flagging-a-post-for-moderator-review)), or very exceptional circumstances that warrant their Other option.  Often feedback to a poster, a community and its moderators is better conveyed via commenting, editing, close voting and/or downvoting rather than flagging.